# Privent Auto mount a partition on 10.7.4

Tags: macos, mount

I made a journaled, Encrypted Partition on 10.7.4

Now every time in startup it asks for the partition password.
I would like to unlock and use this partition when ever I want not every time. So I want Mac leave it and do not ask me the password automatically at the startup every time
iMac, Mac OS X (10.7.4)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to the **/etc/fstab** file:

> LABEL= none hfs ro,noauto

Being `<label>`the name of the encrypted volume.

If you are just wondering, **ro** means *read only* (you should use `rw`instead, if you want to *read and write* after mount).

**Note** that the file could not exist, therefore you'll have create it. To do so just open **/Applications/Utilities/Terminal** and type:

1. sudo vi /etc/fstab
2. This will prompt the password. Type it. It won't be shown, don't worry.
3. Add the already mentioned line.
4. Hit <kbd>Escape</kbd>, type **:wq**, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: You might consider using nano in Apple SE. This is not SU.

Comment: The *instructions* are pretty straight forward, there's no need to be a *Super User* to use them. And he can still use whatever program he wants, of course, this was just a tip. Never used Nano, though.

Comment: If you're on Mac vi is way off the used user experience. nano is easier. Try it!